# Neo4J Very Large Admin Import with limited RAM

Tags: neo4j, bigdata, large-data

I am importing several TB of CSV data into Neo4J for a project I have been working on. I have enough fast storage for the estimated 6.6TiB, however the machine has only 32GB of memory, and the import tool is suggesting 203GB to complete the import.

When I run the import, I see the following (I assume it exited because it ran out of memory). Is there any way I can import this large dataset with the limited amount of memory I have? Or if not with the limited amount of memory I have, with the maximum ~128GB that the motherboard this machine can support.

```
Available resources:
  Total machine memory: 30.73GiB
  Free machine memory: 14.92GiB
  Max heap memory : 6.828GiB
  Processors: 16
  Configured max memory: 21.51GiB
  High-IO: true

WARNING: estimated number of nodes 37583174424 may exceed capacity 34359738367 of selected record format
WARNING: 14.62GiB memory may not be sufficient to complete this import. Suggested memory distribution is:
heap size: 5.026GiB
minimum free and available memory excluding heap size: 202.6GiB
Import starting 2022-10-08 19:01:43.942+0000
  Estimated number of nodes: 15.14 G
  Estimated number of node properties: 97.72 G
  Estimated number of relationships: 37.58 G
  Estimated number of relationship properties: 0.00 
  Estimated disk space usage: 6.598TiB
  Estimated required memory usage: 202.6GiB

(1/4) Node import 2022-10-08 19:01:43.953+0000
  Estimated number of nodes: 15.14 G
  Estimated disk space usage: 5.436TiB
  Estimated required memory usage: 202.6GiB
.......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   5% ∆1h 38m 2s 867ms
neo4j@79d2b0538617:~/import$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL:DR; [Using Periodic Commit](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/neo4j-admin-import/#_import_a_small_data_set), or  [Transaction Batching](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data)

If you're trying to follow the [Operations Manual: Neo4j Admin Import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/neo4j-admin-import/#_import_a_small_data_set), and your csv matches the `movies.csv` in that example, I would suggest instead doing a more manual `USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV...`:

1. Stop the db.
2. Put your csv at `neo4j/import/myfile.csv`.

   - If you're using Desktop: Project > DB > click the ... on the right >
     Open Folder
3. Add the APOC plugin.
4. Start the DB.

Next, open a browser instance, run the following (adjust for your data), and leave it until tomorrow:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///myfile.csv' AS line
WITH line[3] AS nodeLabels, {
  id: line[0],
  title: line[1],
  year: toInteger(line[2])
} AS nodeProps
apoc.create.node(SPLIT(line[3],';',
```

Note: There are *many* ways to solve this problem, depending on your source data and the model you wish to create. This solution is only meant to give you a handful of tools to help you get around the memory limit. If it is a simple CSV, and you don't care about what labels the nodes get initially, and you have headers, you can skip the complex `APOC`, and probably just do something like the following:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///myfile.csv' AS line
CREATE (a :ImportedNode)
SET a = line
```

### File for Each Label

Original Asker mentioned having a separate csv for each label. In such instances it may be helpful to have a great-big single-command that can handle all of it, rather than needing to manually step through each step of the operation.

**Assuming two label-types, each with a unique 'id' property, and one with a 'parent_id' referencing the other label...**

```
UNWIND [
  { file: 'country.csv', label: 'Country'},
  { file: 'city.csv', label: 'City'}
] AS importFile
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///' + importFile.file AS line

CALL apoc.merge.node([importFile.label], {id: line.id}) YIELD node
SET node = line
;

// then build the relationships
MATCH (city :City) 
WHERE city.parent_id
MATCH (country :Country {id: city.parent_id)
MERGE (city)-[:IN]->(country)
```

Comment: I have several CSVs with headers, one file per node or edge type. Would I be able to use the second option here once for each CSV, replacing ':ImportedNode' with the type for the nodes in the given file to get the same output I would have gotten from assigning the labels to the individual files in the admin-import?

Comment: That would do it. (see edit)

Comment: One last note... if you are dealing with TBs of data, I would strongly suggest first experimenting with the import script against smaller samples of the full data to get it all working right.

Comment: Hi, I tested this with one of the smaller node files (~1.5GB) and found it was able to complete the operation at a rate of ~2MB/s. That means importing the data in this manner would take nearly a month of continuous operation. 

Based on the estimates I have from the admin import tool, that method would be doable in less than 2 days. Is there another way I can import the data more time efficiently? The best I can think is to add what RAM I can and make a large SWAP file on the striped NVME setup I have the dataset on- but I imagine this too will have some significant performance drop.

Comment: Shouldn't be that slow. Run your Cypher import with `PROFILE` to check for `EAGER`. Watch your system resources for where the bottleneck is (CPU, ram, disk IO).

Comment: Could the slowness of the query be related to it being Community Edition? I noticed there's some more optimized runtimes that appear to only be available in enterprise edition. I watched my resources when it was running and nothing really seemed like it should have been bottlenecking. What is the EAGER btw?

Comment: Perhaps I should open up another question about optimizing the query more? This discussion is getting kinda large.

Comment: EAGER will load ALL matches. Uses a lot of time and ram. It's old, but worth the read: https://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/